# variable name unresolved

Tags: java

I'm following the Stanford intro to java course and started trying to run a few of the examples they give in Eclipse, but running into a problem.

When I assign the value of rgen to dieRoll, it's telling me "regn cannot be resolved". When I'm naming the RandomGenerator as "rgen" it's saying "The value of the field DiceRoll.regn is not used"

Can anyone tell me why this happening, and how I can correct it so I can run this?! Thanks

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;

public class DiceRoll extends ConsoleProgram {
public void run() {
    int dieRoll = rgen.nextInt(1,6);
    println("You rolled " + dieRoll);
}

/*Private instance variables */
private RandomGenerator regn =
        RandomGenerator.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: Just an advise, put the attributes of the class at the beginning (the first thing I thought was that `rgen` doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `rgen` not `regn` which is your variable name.

```
int dieRoll = rgen.nextInt(1,6);<---rgen not regn
```

Comment: You all managed to post responses while i was frantically trying to delete the post after spotting my spelling mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dex711  So is very fast ;) You can always accept the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

The Object reference declared and the reference u r using are mismatching.
regn and rgen not same change any one...
I hope it will work fine for u.